# How can I use a dynamic table name in the FROM area of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, partitioning, dynamic-sql

**Original question:**
I'm working with a database that generates a new table each month and appends `YYYY_MM` to the new table name. I need to write a query that will look at the table for the current month. Date functions aside, I find I'm unable to build table names!

Example table name would be `DOCUMENTS_2011_10`.

I tried to use a basic script like this but it fails on syntax issue:

```
SELECT * FROM ('DOCUMENTS_'+'2011_10')
```

Any suggestions?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
The tables are being generated by our enterprise portal application (Oracle WebCenter Interaction). It is out of my control to redesign this application to change how it handles its data.

I've been asked to extract a report showing key data from these tables which are generated monthly.

My approach was going to be to create a SQL Reporting Service subscription that will email the data each month in Excel format.
I needed help with this query to plug it into the reporting service so I wouldn't have to dabble with the query each month to change the tablename.

Because the reporting service will trigger each month and generate the reports, an archive of data, or any type of ad hoc capability are not needed.

Using dynamic SQL I was able to set the table name, unfortunately when I try to add the rest of my query it complains of a character limit issue.  Any idea how to get around that?

This gets me the correct table:

```
Declare @tblName Varchar(400)
Declare @SQL Varchar(500)

Set @tblName = 
'analyticsdbuser.ASFACT_DOCUMENTVIEWS_'
+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE())) 
+ '_'
+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(GETDATE())-1), 2));

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @Tblname;
Exec(@SQL)
```

This is the other query that all needs to get executed but won't fit into the @SQL:

```
SELECT   t2.ID,
         t2.USERID,
         t3.NAME,
         t2.DOCUMENTID,
         t1.NAME AS DOC_NAME,
         t4.PROPERTYID,
         t5.NAME AS PROP_NAME,
         t4.VALUE

FROM     ASFACT_DOCUMENTVIEWS_2011_10 AS t2 INNER JOIN
         ASDIM_USERS AS t3 ON t3.USERID = t2.USERID INNER JOIN
         ASDIM_USERPROPERTYVALUES AS t4 ON t4.USERID = t2.USERID INNER JOIN
         ASDIM_KDDOCUMENTS AS t1 ON t1.ID = t2.DOCUMENTID INNER JOIN
         ASDIM_USERPROPERTIES AS t5 ON t4.PROPERTYID = t5.PROPERTYID

WHERE    (t2.DOCUMENTID IN ('33449', '36241', '36566')) AND
         (t4.PROPERTYID IN (26, 156, 157, 158, 159, 325, 160, 162))

ORDER BY t2.DOCUMENTID,
         t3.NAME;
```

**PARTITIONING QUESTION**
I'm unfamiliar with the partitioning concept that some folks have mentioned and will look into it at this time.

In case it matters, each of these monthly tables is only about 20k rows and 1.5mb (we aren't a big company, this software was designed for companies that get millions of rows in each of these monthly tables)

Comment: Have you considered using the partitioning features of SQL server to break up the tables horizontally? If at all you can avoid dynamically named tables it is going to save you lots of headaches with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes, partitioning should be used, if available.  Otherwise... Doesn't completely remove the need for dynamic SQL, but one of the things we did here was to create a temporary _alias_ (dynamically) to the required table, then use the (constant) name of the alias in our SQL.  This also has the effect of, if you make it a _view_ being able to aggregate data from more than one source (say, three months).

Comment: If the dynamic SQL won't fit into the variable, and you're not using partitioning, you could just make the content of the variable shorter. Just grab the one table and put the results into a temp table. Then do your main query again with the temp table instead of the dynamically named table, no dynamic SQL needed for the longer query.

Answer (score 7):

Object and columns names can not be dynamic in SQL Server.

You'd have to use dynamic SQL to build it up, say with sp_executesql

```
...
SET @SQL = 'DOCUMENTS_'+'2011_10';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql ...
```

Saying that, embedding info like this in an object name generally bad practice. What happens if you want 3 months of data in one query?

Comment: Also, be careful because if you do this in a stored procedure it will execute with the permissions of the owner of the PROC not the current user.

Comment: @JohnFx: yep, one reason I don't like dynamic SQL

Comment: ...and there are plenty of reasons to avoid it. Hence a good reason for the OP to reconsider dynamically naming tables like this.

Comment: Thanks for the information it was helpful.  This is part of a giant enterprise application system designed to handle millions of rows of data per month and to have complex reporting (not the way I'm doing it) done on the data.  For my purposes historical data isn't in scope. I strictly need to return the past months information.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more - there are  a numebr of options

1. writing dynamic sql: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3132

   ```
   Set @SQL = 'SELECT * From #TempTable Where EmpID in (' + @INList +')'
   Exec(@SQL)
   ```

   may be what you are looking for, however
2. Have you conisdered partitioned views, and only accessing from the view?  It would have the bemefit of keeping things in their individual tables, yet - provide access to the data as if ti was in one place.

Comment: Your first construct isn't relevant to dynamic table names and is a SQL injection risk

Comment: Thanks for the partitioning suggestion - I will investigate that as the approach I'm taking seems clunky.

Comment: No doubt it is an injection risk, but it did answer the exact question  the user was asking.  The question wasn't "is there a safe way" it was how do i do this exact task.  That is why I gave two answers...